# onClick method error & App crashes when I press the button

Tags: android, onclick, crash

I have a simple app to increase and decrease a number with button press. but unfortunately my app crashes when I press the button. Here is the MainActivity.java code :

```
package com.example.sparker.asafool;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

int quantity = 1;

public void decrement(View view) {
    quantity = quantity - 1;
    displayIt(quantity);
}

public void increment(View view) {
    quantity = quantity + 1;
    displayIt(quantity);
}

public void displayIt(int xyz){
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    quantityTextView.setText(xyz);
}
```

}

decrement and increment methods are in the xml file.

Here is the logcat:

[image: Here is the logcat:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually you have to convert int into String. You can't set integer on `TextView`. As from the logs you can see, here O.S. thinking you passed resource id of `String` resource which never found and it throw `ResourceNotFoundException`.

```
public void displayIt(int xyz) {
 TextView quantityTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
 quantityTextView.setText(""+ xyz); // convert into String
}
```

Comment: Then how can I pass "quantity" which is an integer variable to the DisplayIt method?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to .setText() an int while .setText accepts a string (actually, a CharSequence) as a parameter. Try it like this:

```
quantityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(xyz));
```